# Foreign Key points to the primary key in the same table - SailsJS - Waterline

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, sails.js, waterline

I have a model called Person that has an id and also has a parentID. parentID should point to the Person model. My Person.js file attributes include:

```
id: {
  type: 'integer',
  primaryKey: true,
  unique: true,
  size: 64,
  defaultsTo: function () {
    return IDService.createUniquePersonID().toString();
  }
},

parent: {
  model: 'person'
},

children: {
  collection: 'person',
  via: 'parent'
},
```

No matter what I do I can't get my MySQL DB to show me the table that I am looking for: id (bigint) parent (bigint) and I can't populate the children.

PS: The parent might be null.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Create a new relation that stores id and parentID foreign pairs? Although, that wouldn't exactly help if you wanted to store the nulls... but it would mean you wouldn't have to store the ones that don't have a relationship?

Comment: It is a good point @Gry- but I should be able to create them in the same model I guess. The foreign key can be null sometimes when the db is not in CASCADE status for referential integrity. I am still working on it. There must be a way...

Comment: Your Model looks right to me to accomplish what you want. I have done one-to-many in two different models using an exactly analogous setup. Perhaps something about data-population is not working instead? It may be that Waterline will not create the tables you are looking for until required by the creation of new data?